# unable to remove nameserver from resolv.conf (originally an postfix/policyd-weight error message)

Tags: debian, nameserver

I'm using postfix on my Debian (wheezy) server and have it configured to use policyd-weight as follows in the main.cf file:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                           reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                           permit_mynetworks,
                           permit_sasl_authenticated,
                           reject_unauth_destination,
                           reject_unlisted_recipient,
                           warn_if_reject check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:12525,
                           check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
                           permit
```

A while back the previously working setup started bouncing off e-mails because it could not reach the policyd-weight daemon (hence the warn_if_reject to override the bounce behaviour). I checked the daemon and it's actually running and listening on port 12525:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:12525         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20005/policyd-weigh
```

The following error message states what I thought was at the core of the issue:

```
Feb  1 12:25:34 ginger postfix/policyd-weight[4446]: warning: child: could not open RBL Lookup Socket to config: IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'config' Invalid argument 
Feb  1 12:25:34 ginger postfix/policyd-weight[4446]: warning: child: err: can't resolve "config" to address at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 755, <GEN14499> line 26.#012
```

From this, it appears to me that the problem really is policyd-weight related and is about a problem with DNS resolving. At first, I though that policyd-weight was somehow given a hostname "config" earlier on and tried to resolve *config to an IP address. However, I didn't manage to find any reference to *config* in the policyd-weight configuration files.

**Then I realised that maybe it was the nameserver that policyd-weight had trouble contacting** (this realisation is missing from mosts posts that reference the above postfix/policyd-weight warning message), e.g. it thought there was a nameserver named *config* (there is not in my setup, so that was bound to fail). And indeed, there is something like that in the */etc/resolv.conf* file:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver config
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 213.133.98.98
```

I think the line really should be as follows

```
# nameserver config
```

since that is what most postings on the internet suggest (first four hits on google for *"nameserver config" hetzner*; unable to post more than two links because of reputation) and this configuration is very likely to be inherited from the default config that my hoster uses on their installs (referring to [their nameservers](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Hetzner_Standard_Name_Server/en)):

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original
### Hetzner Online AG installimage
# nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver config
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 213.133.99.99
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a111::add:9898
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a102::add:9999
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:a0a1::add:1010
```

Manually commenting out *nameserver config* in */etc/resolv.conf* and restarting policyd-weight works fine and I can see from the *X-policyd-weight* header in incoming e-mails that everything works fine.

However, I am having trouble to remove or change that line permanently. *resolvconf* does not appear to be using that */etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original* file upon updating, so whenever I run *resolvconf -u* it brings up exactly the version of */etc/resolv.conf* I have quoted above.

*/etc/network/interfaces* does not include any nameservers and as far as I know I am not using NetworkManager, either. Should I use something along the following line to define nameservers in */etc/network/interfaces* (as suggested by the [Debian manual](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#The_resolvconf_program))?

```
dns-nameservers 12.34.56.78 12.34.56.79
```

I would still like to find out where the (uncommented) *nameserver config* line comes from and why *resolvconf* restores it with every update. What would be a good place to start looking?

Comment: Sounds like misconfigured policyd-weight, not postfix or resolver issue. Adding bogus dns entries to avoid the error does not sound right ('config' is not a nameserver unless you have a very creating naming scheme) Yes if you want to set nameservers, use the dns-nameservers directive in interfaces file.

Comment: @Dan Sorry if I didn't make myself clear there. I'm not trying to add nameservers; rather I would like to have *resolvconf* **not** add a (non-existent) nameserver "config" to *resolv.conf*.